# Open file dialog filter options is not displaying xlsx files in the list when selected

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am trying to set filter for OpenFileDialog for excel.

```
@"csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|Excel Worksheets (*.xls; *.xlsx)|*.xls*"
```

The list is displaying the filter options. When I select xls;xlsx option, only xls files are listed. xlsx and xlsm files are not listed.

Am I doing any thing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your Excel extensions with semicolon and the description with colons:

```
@"csv files (.csv)|.csv|Excel Worksheets (*.xls, *.xlsx)| *.xls*"
```

[image]

Comment: I am able to view the xlsx and xlsm files.